# run-time error '3061' to few parameters. expected 1 - access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

/* error in line Set recSet1 = con1.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) */

```
Dim con1 As DAO.Database
Dim recSet1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set con1 = CurrentDb

txNIK.SetFocus
If txNIK.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Masukan NIK"
    err = True
End If
TxPas.SetFocus
If IsNumeric(TxPas) Then
    MsgBox "Format Salah"
    TxPas.SetFocus
    err = True
End If
TxPas.SetFocus

If Not err Then
    sql = "SELECT NIK, Pass FROM Tb_Peg WHERE NIK = txNIK "
    Set recSet1 = con1.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

/* what parameters should i write ? error 3061  */

```
    If recSet1.RecordCount > 0 Then
        'user does exist in database
        MsgBox "You can access the application"
    Else
        'user does not exist
        MsgBox "Your login details do not match"
    End If    'recordcount
    recSet1.Close
    con1.Close
    Set wk = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    Set recSet1 = "Nothing enter code here"
End If
```

/* this codes for validation login in access 2013 *?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL can't see your VBA parameters. Try something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT NIK, Pass FROM Tb_Peg WHERE NIK = '" & txNIK.Text & "'"
```

As an additional precaution, if `txNIK` is supposed to be a number (Integer or Long), I suggest you declare the variable explicitly:

```
Dim txNIK As Integer ' or Long
```

If the value is a String (as I assumed in my query suggestion above), then you should enclose the value in single quotes in your query.